# Display default value if not find in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following situation:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in model.Fields">               
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            {{field.Code}}
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            {{field.Name}}
         </div>                   
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="aaa" ng-repeat="(key, value) in model.FieldSemantics">
                 <span ng-click="">
                     <enum-name-display ng-if="field.Code == key" value="value" values="@Html.ValuesForEnum(typeof(FieldRoleEnum))"></enum-name-display>                                  
                 </span>                           
             </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

model.Fields is array

model.FieldSemantics is an object where key is equal to code of the field and value that is equal to enum value.

I  wanted to show value of enum when field.Code is equal to key. It works good, but for some fields in array there is no equal (key, value) pair in model.FieldSemantics. For this case I would like to show default value f.ex. dash "-". I have no idea how to solve it.

Example json:

```
      "Fields": [
                {
                    "Code": "field1",
                    "Name": "Field 1",
                },
                {
                    "Code": "field2",
                    "Name": "Field 2",
                },
                {
                    "Code": "field3",
                    "Name": "Field 3",
                },
                {
                    "Code": "field4",
                    "Name": "Field 4",
                },
                {
                    "Code": "field5",
                    "Name": "Field 5",
                },
            ]
    "FieldSemantics": {
         "field1": 0,
         "field3": 1,
         "field5": 2
     },
```

Answer (score 2):

Just have enums within your ng-repeat. Use the first one basically like you are and on the second one use something like: `ng-if="! field.Code == key"`

Comment: You mean sth like this:`ng-if="!(field.Code == key)"` . It doesn`t work properly because this creates as many dashes as there are elements in model.FieldSemantics.

Comment: The ng-if expression might be off a bit, but the concept is correct. If you want to add your JSON to your question I can give you the exact expression.

Comment: I added the example json because now I do not have access to resources but given json reflects the situation. So like you can see for field2 and field4 there is no corresponding key in FieldSemantics object. So for this fields I would like display dash. For others I am displaying value according to enum value but that is made using `ng-if="field.Code == key"`

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out in different way. I added to:

```
<enum-name-display ng-if="field.Code == key" value="role(field.Code)" values="@Html.ValuesForEnum(typeof(FieldRoleEnum))"></enum-name-display>
```

This:

```
value="role(field.Code)"
```

And add appropriate function in ctrl:

```
$scope.role = function (code) {
    var fieldSemanticsObj = $scope.model.FieldSemantics;
    var value = 4; // default value
    if (fieldSemanticsObj.hasOwnProperty(code)) 
    {
       value = fieldSemanticsObj[code];
    }
    return value;        
}
```

Maybe it`s not the best solution to achieve desired result but it works :)